# discord.py make bot kick users with specified role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot kick all users with a specified role via a command. I don't recieve any error whatsoever, so I'm kind of clueless whatI should do. Here's my code:

```py
class InactiveCog(commands.Cog):
    def init(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("KickCog loaded")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    @has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content.casefold().startswith("kick alle inaktiven rachel"):
            await message.channel.send('Ab geht die Fahrt. See ya Nerds!')
            for member in message.guild.members:
                role_id = 723107103274958908
                if role_id in member.roles:
                    await self.bot.guild.kick(member)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński okay I corrected it in the last line of the code but still got no error. just sends the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Member.roles` is a list of `discord.Role` instances, not a list of integers so this

```py
if role_id in member.roles:
```

statement is not valid, you can get a `discord.Role` instance with `Guild.get_role`

```py
role = message.guild.get_role(role_id)
if role in member.roles:
    await member.kick()
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.get_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role)